# Making 'proxy' repository

Tags: git

I trying to figure out some sensible solution to be able to track changes across multiple environments.

Basically I have the follwing setup:

[image: connectivity]

I have access to a gitlab repository from MyPC. This repository is not accessible from the internet but only via some VPN connection. In another instance I need to test and devlop code on a remote instance of a PC to which I have only a (encrypted) RDP connection. From the remote PC I have no access to the internet; neither there is a way to connect to the remote gitlab repository. But I do have Windows Network Drive connection to MyPC via RDP.

So I was thinking: is it possible to make changes in remote PC; then to push them to MyPC; and after possibly making other modification to push it to gitlab's remote repository?

I guess I need to figure out some configuration with a bare repository. But honestly I don't have a clue.

Things that I tried/ or trying to avoid:

1. My development environment does not work over the network drive - that would be the most easy solution; but unfortunately thare are some strange issues which I was not able to solve (and it is not so much related to this particular question)
2. I cloned the repository from the network drive - but i cannot push changes to it; git warns me about corrupting the index.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If MyPC can access a fileshare from the remote PC, this would be easier (you'd just add the remote PC's repo as a second remote on the MyPC repo, so that you can `fetch` (and then `merge` (or `rebase`) locally) instead of `push`); but it sounds like that's not the case.

So, you *can* push from the remote PC's repo to the MyPC repo, but by default you can't push to the branch that's currently checked out.  (If MyPC is actively used for development as well, then I recommend *against* changing that default behavior.)

It sounds like you've already added the MyPC repo as a remote on the remote PC's repo (though if you used `/just/a/path/to/the/repo` I'd suggest re-doing it with a `file://localhost/just/a/path/to/the/repo` type URL instead).  Then you just need to set up a `push` refspec that will avoid writing to the branch that the MyPC repo has checked out.  For example if the MyPC is the remote named `origin`, then

```
git config remote.origin.push +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/myRemote/*
```

would set the default behavior on a `push` to map, say, `master` to `myRemote/master`.  (Essentially after a push, it will look in the `myPC` repo as though you had `fetch`ed from a remote named `myRemote`.  You can then merge or rebase changes as usual.)